# Combine multiple .xls files that are formatted as txt files into one pivot?

Tags: excel, vb.net, pivot, powerquery, powerpivot

So I have files that I get from a 3rd party everyday, they have been building up for over a year and I need to combine them into summary pivots, 1 file/pivot for each month.

So I have ~30 files that are .xls files but I think they are formatted as txt files because when I open them I get this notification below, anyway when I save them the defualt is text tab delimited.
[Example of notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3g9k.png)

Each file has the same formatting and the same column headers. My current slow strategy is to open one at a time and paste the contents all into one file, then create a pivot. I know I should be doing this faster using either Power Pivot/Power Query or VB. Which one should I use and can anyone give me hints on how to get started?

Comment: Step 1: open one of those files in a text editor.   If it is in fact text as you suspect that will be readily apparent

Comment: did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in powerquery using either of these options from data ... get data ... from other sources .... blank query  and then home ... advanced editor...

To read and combine all XLS files in a directory

```
//read all files in specified directory you fill in here
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
//filter only filetype xlsx
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

to read and combine all text files (you specify extension) in directory

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
//filter only filetype txt
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".txt")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Csv.Document(File.Contents([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name]),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),"Index")),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", {"Column1", "Index"}, {"Column1", "Index"}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Column1", "Index", "Name"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[Name]), "Name", "Column1"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```